# Let $A =\{(x,y) : x^{2} + y^{2} < 16\}$ and $B = \{(x,y) : y\geq 2\}$. Find the area (measure) of the region $A\cap B$.

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, circles

Let $A =\{(x,y) : x^{2} + y^{2} < 16\}$ and $B = \{(x,y) : y\geq 2\}$.

Find the area (measure) of the region $A\cap B$.

[Graph of A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AtLE.png)

I got this Question for my Year 11 Maths and the suggested solution was using the rules of circle mensuration, but I was wondering if it could be solved by integration or not.

I tried using tutorials online but none made sense to me because they were using relationships with equalities.

Comment: $\int_2^4 \sqrt{16 - y^2} \ dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$ coordinates of the points where the circle $x^2+y^2=16$ and the line $y=2$ meet are $-2\sqrt{3}$ and $2\sqrt{3}$, so you can calculate the area using the following integral: $\int_{-2\sqrt{3}}^{2\sqrt{3}}(\sqrt{16-x^2}-2)dx.$

Comment: So is the integration just using x2+y2=16  and the line y=2 and not the inequalities x2+y2<16 and y≥2? Because I am confused about just this part. And also thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, the inequalities are just for describing the region, setting the bounds of the integral correctly and finding the function to integrate.

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand, thank you so much @closedrhombus, I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: @Alparslan You're welcome! I'm glad my answer was helpful!